# What uses the memory on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

On my pi after start there is no free memory, but i can not found, waht uses it:

```
pi@node1 ~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 2.00
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2708
Revision        : 0013
Serial          : 00000000bf2e5e5c

pi@node1 ~ $ uname -a
Linux node1 4.0.7+ #801 PREEMPT Tue Jun 30 18:15:24 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@node1 ~ $ head -n1 /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l

pi@node1 ~ $ grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         493868 kB

pi@node1 ~ $ grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)

pi@node1 ~ $ ps -eo pmem,pcpu,vsize,pid,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head -5
 0.6  0.2   6244  2377 -bash
 0.3  0.0   6748  2458 sort -k 1 -nr
 0.3  0.0   4140  2457 ps -eo pmem,pcpu,vsize,pid,cmd
 0.2  0.1   9484  2376 sshd: pi@pts/0
 0.2  0.1   5600  2236 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 104:107

pi@node1 ~ $ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        493868     478364      15504          0        500       4956
-/+ buffers/cache:     472908      20960
Swap:       102396        116     102280
```

I am not a linux expert, but if I understand it right, there is just 15Mb free memory, but no task uses more than 0.6%. Than why is not there more free?

Answer (score 1):

Memory is not exclusively allocated by Processes.

- The bootloader and the init ram filesystem is stored in memory.
- The kernel (could be very big) is loaded into memory.
- The kernel reserve memory for it's processes. ps shows 0.0% for these system processes.
- Driver allocate buffer memory
- The graphics card needs memory
- If you have not configured your swap space on a harddrive or SD card, it uses memory.
- The network system allocates memory for unix sockets and shared memory.
- 100 processes with 0.1 % are 10%.

And, if you start a process and stop it not all of it memory will be released.
Try it. Show the memory usage with `free`. Start a process that need some memory. Stop the process and use `free` again. I would bet that there is more memory usage than before.

#### Edit

Here is an example of a pi with less memory usage. I have no problems running java on it. I have a WLAN Dongle and a original NOIR CAM installed.

I installed Raspbian Wheezy. I used a kernel that I compiled from sources:

```
> uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.18.14+ #2 PREEMPT Sun May 31 20:19:04 UTC 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux

> head -n1 /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l
```

On this pi I can run `java -version` in an acceptable period of time.

```
time java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

real    0m1.012s
user    0m0.800s
sys     0m0.190s
```

Here is my memory footprint

```
> free 
            total      used       free       shared   buffers   cached
Mem:        380816     138304     242512     0        8916      96728
-/+ buffers/cache:      32660     348156  
Swap:       102396          0     102396
```

Comment: Ok, but if it is realy so, than I can not use my new PI for general purposes, because the system needs all of memory -> there is no reason to buy a PI!

Comment: The memory management of linux wastes memory as long as there is enough left. Even on a desktop computer with 8 GByte of RAM you will see, that there is only a little amount of free memory. But if you need more memory then the system frees it where possible. But of cause you are right: A raspi is not applicable for all purposes. It is slow and has not much memory. But for some usages it is ideal. It' does not waste much power and has a wonderful graphics system, which allows you viewing videos in realtime. It has GPIOs which allows you to control external hardware.  ...

Comment: I tried to run just a "Java - version", but no response in 10 minutes. It used 180Mb. Is it normal too?

Comment: One upon a time I compiled a linux kernel on a raspi B. The first run last longer the 26 hours. I have no experience with java on a pi. But perhaps this evening (in 6 hours) I'll give it a try. Which version of Java  did you use? Java8?

Comment: Yes, 8 is preinstalled

Comment: I used to think, that java is not installed on a raspi. But you showed me the truth ;-). Yes it's preinstalled, as can not remember to installed it before. That surprises me a bit. `time java -version' uses 1.012 seconds of real time on my rasppi. Not fast but, about a second is good for such a low powered device. I edited my answer, to give you the informations I fouind on me raspberry pi.

Comment: Your pi is much faster! And the used memory is also normal. A try to reinstall it

Comment: I've reinstalled it, and now works fine (used is 63Mb, and time java -version is 1.255s). I do not know, what did I do wrong :( Thank you for your help, Peter!